# My array is not working after second row

Tags: errors, arrays

When I tried with only first and second row it is working but after adding another row it is not working why?

```
$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
x         &    f(x)        &    g(x)      &      h(x) \\ \hline
0.5      & 0.094080   & 0.122417  & {\rm does\,not\,exist}\\ 
-0.5     &0.094080    &0.122417&−0.618033\\
0.02     &1.995203   & 0.124995 & −1.043560\\ 
-0.02    &1.995203   &0.124995&−0.962912\\ 
0.001    &1.999988   &0.124999&-1.002008\\ 
-0.001   &1.999988   &0.124999&-0.998007\\
0.0005   &1.999997  &  0.125   &-1.001002\\ 
-0.0005  &1.999997  &  0.125   &-0.999001\\ 
0.00004  &1.999999  &  0.125   &-1.000080\\
-0.00004  &1.999999  &   0.125  &-0.999920\\
0.000005 &2             &0.12501 &−1.00001\\
-0.000005 &2           &0.12501   & -0.99999\\ 
\end{array}
$$
```

Comment: note `$$` should not be used in latex and `\rm` is not defined by default in latex.

Comment: Your code snippet contains four instances of `−`, which is not the same as the ascii-encoded symbol `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `S` column type defined in `siunitx` package. You may liked:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
  
\[
  \begin{array}{|S[table-format=-1.6]| 
            *{2}{S[table-format= 1.6]|}
                 S[table-format=-1.6]|}
  {x}           & {f(x)}    & {g(x)}    & {h(x)}    \\
    \hline
     0.5        & 0.094080  & 0.122417  & {\text{not exist}}   \\
   -0.5         & 0.094080  & 0.122417  & -0.618033 \\
    0.02        & 1.995203  & 0.124995  & -1.043560 \\
   -0.02        & 1.995203  & 0.124995  & -0.962912 \\
    0.001       & 1.999988  & 0.124999  & -1.002008 \\
   -0.001       & 1.999988  & 0.124999  & -0.998007 \\
    0.0005      & 1.999997  & 0.125     & -1.001002 \\
   -0.0005      & 1.999997  & 0.125     & -0.999001 \\
    0.00004     & 1.999999  & 0.125     & -1.000080 \\
   -0.00004     & 1.999999  & 0.125     & -0.999920 \\
    0.000005    & 2         & 0.12501   & -1.00001 \\
   -0.000005    & 2         & 0.12501   & -0.99999 \\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. :-) You may want to add the option `group-four-digits=true`, either while loading the `siunitx` package or as an option to the first occurrence of `S[table-format=-1.6]`.

Comment: @Mico, as usual, you are right. I will ad this option. Thank you very much!

Comment: In my next homework I will use it thanks :)

Comment: @Preflyt,  why not already now?  Waiting on next homework, where you, as you say,  will not use accepted answer. Hm, a bit strange ...

Comment: @Zarko well I was in a hurry when I posted and directly used the code in first answer and submitted the assignment immediatly.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason you have got non-standard `-` characters in your code. This example works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
    x         & f(x)     & g(x)     & h(x) \\
    \hline
    0.5       & 0.094080 & 0.122417 & \textrm{does not exist} \\
    -0.5      & 0.094080 & 0.122417 & -0.618033 \\
    0.02      & 1.995203 & 0.124995 & -1.043560 \\
    -0.02     & 1.995203 & 0.124995 & -0.962912 \\
    0.001     & 1.999988 & 0.124999 & -1.002008 \\
    -0.001    & 1.999988 & 0.124999 & -0.998007 \\
    0.0005    & 1.999997 & 0.125    & -1.001002 \\
    -0.0005   & 1.999997 & 0.125    & -0.999001 \\
    0.00004   & 1.999999 & 0.125    & -1.000080 \\
    -0.00004  & 1.999999 & 0.125    & -0.999920 \\
    0.000005  & 2        & 0.12501  & -1.00001 \\
    -0.000005 & 2        & 0.12501  & -0.99999 \\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I solved and learned the problem with your help thanks for it!

Comment: Np. Most editors should indicate irregular characters but some don't; I think Overleaf does not do that. BTW, feel free to change the accepted answer if you think it's more to the point or like it more.